# multiplying with mul in nasm in a loop that calls printf - results grow unexpectedly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

i'm trying to use mul and in order to understand it better i wrote a little function and it doesn't make sense to me, the problem is that the multiplications become unstable, that's the code :

```
section .rodata
aformat:    db  "%d", 10, 0 
bformat:    db  "%d", 10, 0 

section .text
    global stam
    extern printf

stam:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp    
    pushad          
    mov ebx,1
    mov eax,2
    mov edx,0
    loop:       
        cmp ebx,120
        jge end
        mul ebx     
        mov ebx,eax
        mov eax,2       
        push ebx
        push aformat
        call printf
        sub esp, 8      
        jmp loop 
    end:
    mov esp,ebp
    popad
    pop ebp
    ret
```

the output is :

```
2
4
8
16
48
144
```

why suddenly after 16 the numbers multiple by 4?

also: when i tried just to multiple eax by a constant 2 assigned to ebx the numbers didn't work at all, i guessed that eax saves the answer for one tick or something... what's the mechanics of mul?

Comment: `eax`  is a caller-save register. If you need to preserve its value across the call to `printf`, store it on the stack temporarily.

Comment: As for why it goes from 16 to 48 specifically: `printf` returns the number of characters written, which in this case is 3 (`'1'`, `'6'`, and LineFeed). Integer return values are returned in the `eax` register, so on the next iteration you'll be multiplying 3 and 16, which is 48.

Comment: Use something like `imul esi, ebx` to keep the product in a call-preserved register instead of using the printf return value.  Or if you want to multiply by powers of 2, use a left shift.